# Difference in executing queries

Tags: graph-databases, memgraphdb

When I'm executing a query on my dataset, ti seems that there's a difference between queries
`MATCH (a)<--(b)-->(c)` and `MATCH (a)<--(b) MATCH (b)-->(c)`.
The first one gives we 486 distinct results and the second one gives me only 334?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say it depends mostly on what you are returning from the query.
Let's say the return clause for the first query is

```
RETURN DISTINCT a, b, c
```

and for the second one

```
RETURN DISTINCT b, c
```

While the second query returns 334 distinct results for the pattern

```
(b)-->(c)
```

the number of distinct results would be larger (or the same) if you included node

```
(a)
```

in the results. This is because you are only returning distinct results. Without

```
DISTINCT
```

if you included node

```
(a)
```

in the results, the number of results would remain the same.